# Image Editing using ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Is there any good image editing component for ASP.NET MVC? That can crop/re-size/rotate etc

Answer (score 1):

As said cropping is easy using the jcrop jquery plugin. That leave you with resizing ,also relatively easy in javascript, the big issue is rotate. For rotating to work you need to work with a canvas (or flash). The canvas element is currently supported by all browsers except for IE. IE has its own kind of canvas implementation.

- [JCROP](http://deepliquid.com/content/Jcrop.html) or [IMGAREASELECT](http://odyniec.net/projects/imgareaselect/) for cropping
- [jRotate](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-rotate/) for rotating
- [resizer](http://tinyjs.com/files/projects/jquery-resizer/index.html) for basic resizing, although just look for a better one

Just remember this is just client side code, and you'll need to do a lot of work in order to combine all the functionality of the three needed plugins.

Once you have it working on the client, you'll have to find a way to dump all of the parameters into hidden fields and send it to the server. On the server you'll need System.Drawing to actually change the image.

A good place to start finding good plugins is either [Google](http://www.google.com) or [jQuery Plugin repository](http://plugins.jquery.com/)

Answer (score 0):

There is an integrated image filtering/editing solution available as a `java-script editor` using `HTML5` canvas properties. **[Fabric](http://fabricjs.com/demos/)**, it has tons of editing options available.

Also, if you wish to use `ASP.NET WebForms Telerik RADImageEditor` in mvc, you could read [**this post**](http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/aspnet-ajax/image-editor/imageeditor-in-asp-net-mvc.aspx) which renders it in Iframe in an mvc view.